# How to enable multiple choice in symfony2 form field: collection

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have a user registration form (that the admin uses) and I want to include the choices for role. I have successfully added a drop-down of roles with the following code in my buildForm function:

```
    $builder
        ->add('roles', 'collection', array(
            'type'   => 'choice',
            'options'  => array(
                'choices'  => array(
                    'ROLE_CONTENT' => 'Innehåll',
                    'ROLE_LAYOUT'     => 'Skärmlayout',
                    'ROLE_VIDEO'    => 'Videouppladdning',
                    'ROLE_ADMIN'    => 'Administratör',
                ),
            ),
    ));
```

Now, I want this to be a multichoice or list of checkboxes instead of a dropdown, but I can't seem to find a way, seems like a simple enough thing to do or am I missing something about how this field type works, can it not take multiple choices?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the `collection` type here. The `choice` type with "multiple" set to `true` will output a collection just fine.

```
$builder
    ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'choices'  => array(
            'ROLE_CONTENT' => 'Innehåll',
            'ROLE_LAYOUT'  => 'Skärmlayout',
            'ROLE_VIDEO'   => 'Videouppladdning',
            'ROLE_ADMIN'   => 'Administratör',
        ),
    ))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you are using `collection` as [`choice`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) type, which means you can use [`expanded` and `multiple` options](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons) to render any of four element types you want.

Comment: This is not true. Collection extends FormType, not ChoiceType.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Answer (score 0):

The expanded works fine, gives me radio buttons, but I want checkboxes.

This works for radios:

```
    $builder
        ->add('roles', 'collection', array(
            'type'   => 'choice',
            'options'  => array(
                'expanded' => true,
                'choices'  => array(
                    'ROLE_CONTENT' => 'Innehåll',
                    'ROLE_LAYOUT'     => 'Skärmlayout',
                    'ROLE_VIDEO'    => 'Videouppladdning',
                    'ROLE_ADMIN'    => 'Administratör',
                ),
            ),
    ));
```

If I put this however, it throws an error "Expected argument of type "array", "string" given":

```
    $builder
        ->add('roles', 'collection', array(
            'type'   => 'choice',
            'options'  => array(
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'choices'  => array(
                    'ROLE_CONTENT' => 'Innehåll',
                    'ROLE_LAYOUT'     => 'Skärmlayout',
                    'ROLE_VIDEO'    => 'Videouppladdning',
                    'ROLE_ADMIN'    => 'Administratör',
                ),
            ),
    ));
```